# What is a List vs. an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

What are the fundamental differences between the two objects? Is one more efficient? Does one have more methods?

Comment: gosh, *this* has never been asked before! To the OP, consider searching the forum first before asking.

Comment: @Hovercraft, are you sure it's *never* been asked before?

Comment: Voting to reopen - I don't think the linked post is a duplicate. It's about coding to interface vs. implementation, whereas this is actually asking what the difference between `List` and `ArrayList` is.

Comment: The question doesn't talk about List w.r.t. Java. A generic answer would be - "List is an ordered collection".

Answer (score 24):

List is in interface while ArrayList is a class.

See [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

E.g, you can't use this setup:

`List<String> list = new List<String>();`... Because it's an interface.

However, this works:

`ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Also... You can do as duffymo says below, which is more or less the same as implementing the `List` interface (making your own list implementation).

Comment: No, but you can do this: List<String> list = new List<String>() {// implement all List methods here.};

Comment: Fun fact: The magical creature that @duffymo created is actually known as an `anonymous inner class`.  ;)

Answer (score 23):

Consider a line like the following:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you're new to object-oriented architectures, you might have expected instead to see something like `ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();`. After all, you've just said that it's a new `ArrayList`, so shouldn't you store it in a variable of type `ArrayList`?

Well, you certainly can do that. However, `List` is an interface--like a template of sorts--that `ArrayList` is said to inherit. It is a contract that says "anytime you use a `List` implementation, you can expect these methods to be available". In the case of `List`, the methods are things like `add`, `get`, etc.

But `ArrayList` is only one implementation of `List`. There are others, such as `LinkedList`. The two have the same interface, and can be used the same way, but work very differently behind the scenes. Where `ArrayList` is "random" access, meaning that it directly finds a specific element of the array without iterating through the whole list, `LinkedList` does have to start from the first element and go one-by-one until it gets to the element you need.

The thing is, while you do need to specify which you want when you create the object, you generally only need to communicate no more than the fact that it is a `List`, so you simply say that's what it is. `List` communicates that you have a collection that is intended to be in the order that it is given. If you don't need to communicate that much, you might consider passing it around as a `Collection`, which is another interface (a super-interface of `List`). Or, if all you need to communicate is that you can iterate over it, you might even call it an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 14):

List is an interface; ArrayList is a class that implements the List interface.

Interfaces define the method signatures that are required, but say nothing about how they are implemented.

Classes that implement an interface promise to provide public implementations of methods with the identical signatures declared by the interface.

Answer (score 2):

A `List` defines the interface that `ArrayList` uses, that allows it to implement methods that will allow all other classes that implement List to be used together or in a similar way. An `ArrayList` is always also a `List`, but an `List` isn't necessarily an `ArrayList`.

That is, `ArrayList` implements `List` (among a few other interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

How to use List and `ArrayList`, or other implementation of List, is `Polymorphism` and `Inheritance`, and also the reason why for using languages such as Java.

In simplicity, Polymorphism is many forms while Inheritance is reuse.

There can be many kinds of concrete and ready to us List that is available to you, such as ArrayList, `Vector`, `LinkedList` and `Stack`. The decision to use which comes from you, and if you look at the [List API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), you would notice that all of these List implementations extend in one way or another from List.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), List is just an interface, and ArrayList is one of the classes that implement it. There is no inherent efficiency advantage to using ArralyList specifically instead of List-typed references to an ArrayList object.

However, when it comes to "efficiency", there can be a difference between different implementations of the List interface. For instance there can be  a small efficiency difference between a LinkedList and an ArrayList, depending on how you're using them.

To quote the java docs on the [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) page,

> The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

In other words, the performance difference will probably be negligible, but you may see some advantage from using an ArrayList (as opposed to a LinkedList).

In case you're interested, ArrayList is implemented with an array that is resized from time to time (most likely whenever your collection doubles in size), which is quite different from the implementation of a LinkedList (see wikipedia for details).

Comment: He isn't. He is asking when he should use List and when you should use ArrayList. LinkedList doesnt come into it - as all the previous answers might have indicated. LinkedList is a misdirection for this particular question.