# java - what is the difference between a list and an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a List vs. an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867484/what-is-a-list-vs-an-arraylist)

Ive used both of them, but im just wondering what are the pros and cons between them? What are the major differences? And which one is better to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List` is an *interface* implemented by `ArrayList` *class*. Another well-known implementation of the `List` is `LinkedList`.

`ArrayList` provides constant-time random access, while `LinkedList` provides constant time for non-sequential access. When you declare a variable that will hold an `ArrayList`, consider accessing it through an interface, like this:

```
List<ElementType> myList = new ArrayList<ElementType>();
```

This will let you swap in a different implementation without disturbing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) merely describes the contract of what it means to be a list. As such, it is not a concrete implementation but merely an *interface*. A list can be implemented in a number of ways.

In particular, you have [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which internally keeps a dynamic array for storing all the elements in order. You also have [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which stores elements as a *doubly linked list* i.e. a sequence of nodes which keep references to the previous and next nodes.

[`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) is another `List`, much like an `ArrayList` in that its implementation is based on a dynamic array;  it's, however, a relic of the older versions of Java and is guaranteed to be thread-safe by being wholly synchronized. In practice,  `new Vector<T>()` is more-or-less equivalent to [`Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29).

The reason for having a `List` is that a list can come implemented in a number of ways. That being said, often you want to have some sort of generic behavior that can be applicable to all `List`s... see [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 1):

A **List** is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), and an **ArrayList** is an implementation of that interface. An ArrayList is a List, and so are LinkedLists, Stacks, Vectors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the other posters already answered the "what" part of your question.  Some considerations to think about when choosing between them.

An ArrayList uses an array behind the scenes.  So accessing by index can be done in constant time.  Adding can also be done in constant time, if the array has been allocated with enough space.  However, when the space runs out, ArrayList will allocate a larger array and copy the old array values into the new one.

A LinkedList uses nodes that are chained together.  Accessing by an index can potentially require walking the entire list (linear time).  Inserting only requires creating a new node and adding it at the end (which could be constant time if a tail pointer is maintained).

So "which one is better" can depend on how you are using it.  Truthfully, I've never measured performance differences between the two, but it's just something to consider.