# array lists in java: exclude the first element from `for` loop

Tags: arraylist, methods

I am taking an introduction to Java programing class and I have an array list where I need to exclude the first element from my for loop that finds an average. The first element in the array list is a weight for the average (which is why it needs to be excluded). I also need to drop the lowest value from the remainder of the array list hence my second for loop. I have tried to create a copy of the list and also tried to create a sub list but I cannot get it to work.

```
public static double Avgerage(ArrayList<Double> inputValues) {
    double avg;
    double sum = 0;
    double weightValue = inputValues.get(0);
    double lowest = inputValues.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i > inputValues.size(); i++) {
        if (inputValues.get(i) < lowest) {
            lowest = inputValues.get(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + inputValues.get(i);
    }
    double average = (sum - lowest) / (inputValues.size() - 1);

    avg = average * weightValue;

    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with good programming practice, you should work with interfaces rather than classes, where possible. The appropriate interface here is `List<Double>`, and when you create it in your class, you should use

```
List<Double> nameOfList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

What we're doing is creating an object which has the behaviour of a List, with the underlying implementation of an ArrayList (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867484/what-is-a-list-vs-an-arraylist#answer-6867567).

With regards to the question, you don't appear to be excluding the first element, as you said you wished to - both for loops iterate through all values in the list. Remember to treat the ArrayList like an array - accessing an element does not modify it, like it might in a Queue.

I have edited your code below to demonstrate this, and have also included some other optimisations and corrected the sign error on line 7:

```
public static double average(List<Double> inputValues) {
    double sum = 0;

    //Exclude the first element, as it contains the weight
    double lowest = inputValues.get(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < inputValues.size(); i++) {
        lowest = Math.min(inputValues.get(i), lowest);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < inputValues.size(); i++) {
        sum += inputValues.get(i);
    }

    double average = (sum - lowest) / (inputValues.size() - 1);

    //Scale by the weight
    avg *= inputValues.get(0);

    return avg;
}
```

Note: The convention in java is to use camelCase for method names, I have adjusted accordingly.

Also, I don't know your requirements, but optimally, you should be providing logical parameters. If possible do the following before calling the function:

```
int weight = inputValues.get(0);
inputValues.remove(0);
//And then you would call like this, and update your method signature to match
average(inputValues, weight);
```

I don't do this inside the method, as the context implies that we would not be modifying values.

Comment: Unfortunately the assignment requires that I use the array list. That being said if I use the code you gave me as an example shouldn't it still at least drop the next lowest number excluding the first element? I tried it a few times and its still only dropping the first element.

Comment: Are you sure? lowest should be the lowest number, excluding the first element, and that is subtracted from the sum when average is calculated.

Comment: This code can still use the ArrayList implementation, it's just open to other options as well. If the assignment requires ArrayList specifically in the function signature, then use that, it's functionally identical, but hopefully you will cover interfaces soon, so as not to reinforce bad practice!